# Event schema for events with unknown (TBD) date

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

On our project, we receive events that have the unknown `startDate` that should be defined later.
For events with the unknown start hour [Google suggests](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/event) passing just date: `"startDate": "2025-07-21"`.

But what should we pass if the date is also unknown?

Comment: According to schema.org at least, you could pass in simply the year if you at least know that.